# Unable to turn on iCloud Keychain

Tags: icloud, keychain

I'm using iCloud keychain with multiple devices but when trying to turn it on on my new iPad (running iOS 12.3) the setting is not saved, so if I choose Keychain and turn on iCloud Keychain, and then get back to the iCloud settings, they Keychain option remains off.

I've been trying to restart the iPad, logout and login to iCloud but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Apple support advice solved the problem:

1. Reset network settings
2. Logout and login
3. Reset all settings

Comment: For me this problem was created after logging out of iCloud and back in. The only thing I had to do to correct it was to log out of and back into iCloud _again_. Resetting of settings was not necessary in my case.

Comment: Logging out from iCloud and then in again solved it for me.

Comment: Did this fix persist? Log out and in again works temporarily for me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to approve the iCloud activation from another device. It may pay to check your Apple ID has a valid phone number associated, so you can receive an SMS verification.

From Apple Support https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204085:

> If you can't access any of your other devices that are using iCloud Keychain, you can still set up iCloud Keychain on another device if you have these items:
>
> 1. Your iCloud Security Code
> 2. The device that is using the SMS-capable phone number you provided when you first set up iCloud Keychain. A verification code is sent via SMS to this phone number. If you can't access this number, contact Apple Support, who can verify your identity, so that you can complete setup on your new device.
>
> After you complete the setup, your iCloud Keychain will be pushed from the cloud to the new device.
>
> If you use two-factor authentication with your Apple ID, enter your password and the six-digit verification code that's automatically displayed on your trusted devices and authorize the new device. Then turn on iCloud Keychain.

Comment: I already approved the new device when signing it up with iCloud. When I try to enable type iCloud Keychain I am not being prompted to enter a security code.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 15

After login into icloud, you can be prompted about Merge or Do not merge data. I think if you choose "do not merge", you will not be able to turn on Keychain.

After logout icloud -> reset all settings -> login and choosing merge, then the Keychain was turned on.